# Way to use inherited objects in swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop, inheritance

I have an object that might look something like this...

```
class User {
    var username: String?
}
```

I'd like to have users that could either be a student or a teacher. At the moment, I've added in properties to the User class like this...

```
class User {
    var username: String?
    // student properties
    var year: Int?
    // teacher properties
    var department: String?
}
```

I'm sure I should be using inheritance here, but I'm worried that's going to make the control flow a bit complicated. For example, as part of the login function, I do this...

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
 appDelegate.user = User(delegate: self)
 appDelegate.user!.load_from_user_defaults()
```

Or to get something from the current user, I would do this...

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
 var username = appDelegate.user.username
```

How would I use inheritance, in this situation, given that I wouldn't know if it was a teacher or a student logging in? Is it easier to stick to the way I'm doing it?

Comment: Since you have different attributes for student and teacher, I assume you must have a way of deciding which you're dealing with at some point.

Comment: Hint 1: don't ever use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate` in your application but pass the reference to your value to the view controllers, starting from AppDelegate. Hint 2: Use the Factory Pattern - just google it. You can instantiate an instance of any of these classes via a static method of the superclass for example. Then you can access the username any time. Checking if someone is a Student: `myVariable is Student`. Accessing a variable of a student: `(myVariable as? Student)?.year` returns the year as optional (nil when it isn't a student, the value otherwise)

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I appreciate the advice. Looks like I've still got a lot of reading to do! When you say don't ever use the UIApp... line, is there a good reason not to? I'd like to understand _why_ I'm writing something, rather than just what to change it to. I can see how you might do this using prepareForSegue e.g. [link](http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/), but does that create a copy of object, or retain the original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

- Super/Sub class pattern (**inheritance**) where you use `downcast` to check if it is a Student or a Teacher.
- Protocols work the same as the Super/Sub pattern but a `type` can **conform** to many `protocols` but can only inherit from one `super`.
- if both Student and Teacher have the same properties you can also just add a property (a `bool` or an `enum`) to determine which is which.
- create an `enum` instead of a `protocol` or `super class` that has a `rawValue` of `User` and has cases for both Teacher and Student. (this is complicated)
- Use an `enum` with associated values.

Every method has it's own benefits and drawbacks.
If you want to be able to pass a `User` object to different functions in your app, you want to have some conformance/inheritance.

---

If you have some conformance/inheritance, you can load the user with a method of your choosing and then downcast as such:

```
if let student = user as? Student {
    // do student stuffs
} else if let teacher = user as? Teacher {
    // do teacher stuffs
}
```

---

Option 1, regular inheritance :

```
class User {
    var username: String?
}

class Student : User {
    // student properties
    var year: Int?
}

class Teacher : User {
    // teacher properties
    var department: String?
}
```

---

Option 2, conform to instead of inherit from, AKA Protcols :

```
protocol User : class {
    var username: String? { get set }
}

class Student : User {

    var username: String?
    // student properties
    var year: Int?
}

class Teacher : User {

    var username: String?
    // teacher properties
    var department: String?
}
```

---

Option 3, `UserType` property:

```
enum UserType {
    case Student
    case Teacher
}

class User {
    var username: String?
    // student properties, if it is a teacher we leave this blank
    var year: Int?
    // teacher properties,, if it is a student we leave this blank
    var department: String?

    var type : UserType?
}
```

---

Option 4, `enum` with `User` as `rawValue`:

```
class User: Equatable,StringLiteralConvertible {

    var username: String?
    // student properties
    var year: Int?
    // teacher properties
    var department: String?

    var type : String?

    init(withType type:String) {
        self.type = type
    }

    required convenience init(stringLiteral value: String) {

        self.init(withType: value)
    }

    required convenience init(extendedGraphemeClusterLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(withType: value)
    }

    required convenience init(unicodeScalarLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(withType: value)
    }
}

func ==(lhs:User,rhs:User) -> Bool {
    if lhs.username == rhs.username && lhs.department == rhs.department && lhs.year == rhs.year && lhs.type == rhs.type {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}


enum UserType : User {

    case Student = "Student"
    case Teacher = "Teacher"

}

let user = UserType.Teacher
```

---

Option 5, `enum` with associated values:

```
class User {

    var username: String?

}

class Student {
    // student properties
    var year: Int?
}

class Teacher {
    // teacher properties
    var department: String?
}


enum UserType {
    case student(Student)
    case teacher(Teacher)
}
```

Comment: to be frank ......this is common in all OOP languages
java--interfaces
Swift--protocol
C++, C#.......cool

Comment: haa...yes its smart enough to catch the point  about inheritance in OOPs

Answer (score 0):

"Could be either this or that": In Swift, you use an enumeration. One class for student, one class for teacher, one enumeration for "student or teacher".